# Convert Word Documents to Wiki Pages

Tags: wiki, word, conversion

Has anyone found a solution (custom code, free, or paid) to easily convert Word documents to SharePoint 2010 Wiki Pages?

The closest thing I have found so far is this old 2007 project: http://mosswikipublish.codeplex.com/.  I deployed it to my 2010 farm without issue, but it doesn't work.  It doesn't error out, just doesn't create Wiki pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be something to look into (note: I have no experience with the product).

Bamboo Wiki Publisher

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pfi-159-wiki-publisher.aspx

Comment: YES! That is exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a Look to the sharepointwikiplugin Project on Codeplex. I'm using this to convert our Word Documention in Sharepoint Wiki pages.

https://sharepointwikiplugin.codeplex.com/

(Note that I am the creator of the plugin)

Comment: This is exactly what the OP seems to be looking for, but you should typically let everyone know that you're involved with a project when you suggest your own work as an answer on stackexchange

Comment: @GüntherErb i am intersted in trying your product ,, but is there a full documentation on how to use it and install it , as i did not find any ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a version of the Bamboo solution that supports SharePoint 2013 yet but just so as you know, there is a new product out there that does this for SharePoint 2010 and 2013 and it can even publish wiki pages to SharePoint online.  There's a free trial of course and you don't even need to register to download it.

There is a quick 5 minute video and more info here.

http://www.kaboodlekonnect.com/renditions

It doesn't do the conversion back that the Bamboo Wiki Publisher does i.e. take existing wiki pages and saving them as PDF but it does do automatic synchronisation.  So if you can configure a library so that when a source document is updated the wiki page gets updated automatically.