# Convert Word document into wiki page + Export wiki pages into PDF or word document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, word, enterprise-wiki

We are using a site collection of type enterprise wiki inside SP 2013 Enterprise edition. Now we are facing these two problems, where our customers keep reporting and complaining about:-

1. They already have many large word documents around 50 pages of text and images, and they need to convert the word doc into a wiki page. Now if they try to copy/paste the 50 pages from word to wiki everything will be pasted except the images … so is there a way to either allow pasting images directly inside the wiki pages ? or to convert the word to the wiki ?
2. Also, they have wiki pages that they need to export as pdf or word? So does SharePoint support converting wiki pages into either MS Word or pdf?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem back with SharePoint 2010. Ultimately, we never found a solution, and users were forced to manually upload the images.

However, I do remember that copying and pasting using Firefox embedded the images using base64 encoded strings. So the images were never uploaded into the Images library, but were instead embedded into the HTML markup of the wiki page.

If the word files are as large as you say, then the markup is going to be pretty huge, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Give it a go to see if Firefox still works like that with the SharePoint 2013 out of the box editor.

**Edit:**
Here's a screenshot of it working in SharePoint 2010.. not sure about SP 2013, but it's worth a try to see if it's feasible. You may need to click on 'copy' and 'paste', as opposed to ctrl+c, ctrl+v.
[image]

Comment: So close and yet so far. Yes base64 embed still there in SP2013, until you save the page. "All" that's needed is a script to extract that base64 embed and save it as an image in the library. I found such a beast on [pm.stackexchange.com](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/4353/29936) in comment to an answer that [shares code](http://jsfiddle.net/KJW4E/83/), but how to implement is left out.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could do that with some custom development (I would suggest aspose for .net, see http://www.aspose.com/ - not free but awesome.)
2. Not out of the box - there are components for that, too. See http://www.aspose.com/sharepoint/pdf-component.aspx

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with aspose :)

Comment: thanks for the reply it does not matter if u are affiliated with aspose or not as long as i can find a solution for my problem :) ... regarding the first point you mentioned it requires custom development ? so you mean that aspose.com does not provide a ready made solution for this ?

Comment: Aspose SharePoint is for exporting. Aspose Word can be used to extract the text and create wiki pages with it. To answer your question: no, aspose does not offer a ready made solution for 1.

Comment: so how i will implement the first requirement if i chose to go with aspose ?

Comment: I would read the word file with aspose and export it to html - then i would create a new sharepoint wiki page and add the html. Could be more complicated depending on the word files (e.g. containing images) and other requirements.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but seems not a straight forward task what do u think, especially for non-technical end user ... ?

Comment: Without development you wont make it work - as far as I know there is no product for that yet.

Comment: i download the aspose.pdf but seems it only support SP 2010 and not SP 2013

Comment: where do you read that? aspose.pdf is SharePoint independant and used for reading and writing pdfs - i don't see the dependency.

Comment: ,, in the following link http://www.aspose.com/sharepoint/pdf-component.aspx they mentioned the following "Aspose.Pdf for SharePoint is designed to be used with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 and Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010. The component installs quickly and is easy to use." also when i downlaod the zip folder it have the following name "Aspose.Pdf.SharePoint2010.zip" !1 so seems it does not support SP 2013

Answer (score 0):

1. Third-party software is needed to convert a word document directly to a wiki ([Convert Word Documents to Wiki Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25142/convert-word-documents-to-wiki-pages)). Another option you might consider is embedding the Word documents directly into pages with a script editor and an iframe, but you would have long loading times for documents as large as you're dealing with. Pictures have to be copied separately or inserted to make it into a Wiki page, so that's an option, too.
2. Bamboo offers software that exports pages to PDFs (you'll find a link to them in the link above). Haven't seen another way to do this.

Comment: do you know additional companies other than Bamboo ? just to have other options ... in all ways i will contact them regarding this ...

Comment: I don't personally know of others--sorry!

Comment: one note is that inside the following  http://store.bamboosolutions.com/kb/article.aspx?id=12955&cNode=8Q8H1C regarding the Wiki Publisher limitation they mentioned that the wiki publisher has "No support for SharePoint Enterprise Wiki Publishing Site. " , but in our case we are using site collection of type enterprise wiki ,, so does this mean that the wiki publisher will not work on it ?

Comment: Ah, that's rough...sure sounds like that's what it's saying.

Comment: so if we need to have these 2 features; 1) the ability to convert MS word into wiki pages 2) the ability to export Wiki pages into PDFs ,, then is there a way to achieve this ??? not sure why SharePoint does not provide these features by defualt ....

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint. The things you'd think should be there aren't.

Comment: so what are the approaches i can follow to achieve this ? we already have MS word documents that we want to have inside the Wiki ,, also we need to export the wiki to Pdfs to be able to send them by email ,, any workarounds ?

Comment: I think you'll find yourself out of luck with exporting to PDFs, but importing is more "possible." You can try embedding the documents in the page through an iframe and view it that way, without ever "opening" it.

Comment: but for me adding iframe will be an option to follow, but as you know the users who are using the wiki site are non-technical people, so i can not mentione to them that they need to use iframe..

Comment: If you're going to have a wiki admin, you could consider training your users to build "articles" in Word, at which point your admin would add the iframe. As long as a base document per Wiki page exists, the page could be "edited" through the document library. It's clunky and not that handy, but that's about the only way I can think of getting your existing Word documents involved without another way to import into Enterprise Wikis.

Answer (score 0):

One method that I have seen is to use the publishing features of Word to publish the document to a Sharepoint wiki. Once published, the HTML is taken from the blog and pasted into the wiki page. This is found by going to the File tab, Share, and using the Post to Blog option.

Users accessing your wiki pages need to have read access on the blog to be able to view the pictures.

This method doesn't require any special plug-ins or code, just uses the native features and integration between Word and Sharepoint.

[Here](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=sharepoint%20word%20publish%20to%20blog%20kerri&d=4740043290905182&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=2xKJ1Tm6WMFrhbzgPJbW7acMQjmBkUZb) is an example and [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/15/publish-a-post-to-sharepoint-2013-blog-using-word-2013/) is another.

Comment: can you please adivce more on this ?  i mean how i can find the publishing features of the word ?

Comment: File tab, Share, Post to Blog

Comment: i can not find a Share tab under file, i have "File >> Save& Send >> "Publish as blog Post" ... is this the same ? i tried this but i receive the following error when i click on Publish "Word can not Publish Pictures in this Post.."

Comment: That should be it yes, sounds like we are on different versions of Word. There should be a mapping for where pictures are to be stored.

Comment: i am using MS word 2010 i tried this but it raised an error "Word can not Publish Pictures in this Post.."  , also i am using Enterprise wiki and not blog,,, i got confused ... will posting to a blog be able to publish the word doc to a wiki site ????

Comment: You create a blog subsite and publish to that. Once published to the blog, you go to the blog and get the html, then paste that in the wiki

Comment: edited to add a couple references

Comment: ok i got your point , but i do not think it will be an acceptable solution for our end users,, as seems it requires many manual operations and also we will need to create an un-necessay Blog site collection !! from my site it is a good solution , but for end users it will be rejected..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "BlueBridge Wiki Extensions" might help you. In the versions for SP 2013 and 2016 you can import Word documents to your wiki (enterprise wiki and standard wiki). PDF Export of one or more wiki pages is also integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MS is unable to provide simple Office to HTML converter module for sharepoint 2013 wiki.
To date I devised this solution to get something fast and clean:
1st stage require LibreOffice to batch-convert your .doc/.docx to .html

```
path to your LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --convert-to html your_file.doc
```

2nd, advanced stage if you want to clean up it, removing fonts and clutter, leaving heading marks and basic formatting (requires perl):

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open( T, '< :raw', $ARGV[0] ) or die "$ARGV[0]: $!";
my $out = $ARGV[0];
$out =~ s/\.html?$//i;

$out .= '.mswiki';

my $count = read(T, my $text, 999999999);
close( T );

if( !defined( $count ) || $count < 0 )
{
  die "Read error: $!";
}

$text =~ s/<([^\s>]+)[^>]*>/<$1>/gm; # remove tag attributes

$text =~ s/^.*<body>//s;
$text =~ s/<\/body>.*$//s;

$text =~ s/<\/?(col|font|img|span)>//gm; # completely remove unfixable
$text =~ s/\&nbsp;//gm;
$text =~ s/<([^p][^>]+)>\s*<\/\1>//gs; # remove tags w/o content

$text =~ s/<table>/<table border=1>/g;

open( O, '>', $out ) or die "$out: $!";
print O $text;
close( O );
```

Run in like:

```
clean4mswiki.pl your_converted_doc.html
```

This will produce clean your_converted_doc.mswiki file with less garbage.

I'm still working on automatic wiki poster tool, but it is 50/50 success rate as MS send too much cryptic data along the HTTP POST there.