# Convert Documents with Images to a wiki site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, word, wiki-pages

We're using SharePoint server 2013. I have a Document with Images on my computer desktop.

I want to try to copy a word document that has images to a wiki site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OOTB Copy/Paste operation, The **images** will not be copied to SharePoint page (whatever it's a wiki page or other type) from a word document.

Only the text and tables and some font format will be copied but the images must be uploaded to SharePoint or taken from a published URL to can be used within SharePoint Page.

---

**The available workarounds:**

- Using `Share` feature in your word document to share its content to a SharePoint blog. Then move its Source HTML Code to your Wiki page.
- Use [MS Word SharepointWiki Plugin](https://sharepointwikiplugin.codeplex.com/)
- Use a 3rd party tool like [Bamboo Wiki Publisher](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pfi-159-wiki-publisher.aspx) to import from word document to wiki page.

Check other suggestion at [Convert Word document into wiki page + Export wiki pages into PDF or word document](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138370/convert-word-document-into-wiki-page-export-wiki-pages-into-pdf-or-word-docume)